# How to represent a mathematical expression in memory

Tags: symbolic-math, algebra

Me and my friends are trying to implement a computer algebra system.
We have already implemented an algorithm that converts an expression like 1+2*4 to a binary tree

```
  +
 / \
1   *
   / \
  2   4
```

And we implemented an algorithm that evaluates this kind of binary tree.
We now want to implement an algorithm that simplifies expressions with variables.
For example, x+2x will become 3x
I was thinking it would be easier to merge similar operators in the binary tree. For example:

```
  +  
 / \  
a   +  
   / \  
   b  c
```

will become

```
   +
 / | \  
a  b  c
```

This way it would be easier to find terms that can be simplified.
For example, if I had x+2x+3x in my expression then they would be under the same + operator and thus they can find each other much easier without traversing most of the tree.

My friend thinks that we should implement the tree in a different approach. He suggested that we should implement each node as a polynomial, and then we can make operations such as polynomial addition between nodes. Using this approach we can make operations between polynomials much easier, without going back and forth the tree.

Which approach should we choose? is there a better approach other than these two?

Comment: This is a broad question. What kind of polynomials and their operations are you looking for? What have you tried so far matters as well.

Comment: For polynomial addition, use linked lists either singly/doubly linked. Each node represents coefficient, variable, sign. Just a thought.

Comment: Or only if simplification is concerned with addition/subtraction, maintain a unordered map that maps variables to its coefficient and update accordingly.

Comment: I don't want my software to simplify only polynomials, I want it to also simplify things like cos^2(x) + sin^2(x) to 1.
For now, simplifying polynomials would be a good start but I want it to be able to simplify more complex expressions later on.
I am trying to decide whether I should store a single operand or an operator
in a single node in the tree or should I store an entire polynomial in each node.
by polynomial I mean an expression of the form a+bx+cx^2+dx^3... which can be represented as a linked list, as you said.

Comment: You're off to a great start, you have already identified some of the fundamental problems that need to be solved. A web search for "implementation computer algebra systems" should turn up some resources. Incidentally you might consider working in Lisp (Common Lisp or Scheme or whatever) since Lisp was originally devised in part to work on such problems. You might want to organize your system as a pattern matching (in the sense of unification of expressions, not string matching) engine plus a list of rules, representing identities, to be applied. Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Maybe it can help: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352711017300146. In that implementation simplification rules are included in the specific operation and executed recursively until no new simplification is performed on the graph